# How to disable introspection and load a schema from a String in WunderGraph?

Tags: typescript, graphql, prisma, introspection

I am currently building a full stack application and having some performance issues with my service due to introspection. I would like to disable introspection for some services and rather load my schema using a string.

I tried looking at the [documentation](https://docs.wundergraph.com/docs/wundergraph-config-ts-reference/configure-introspection#disable-introspection-caching) and followed along the steps to solve it but when I load it from a string, the service is still being accessed by WunderGraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loadSchemaFromString for this:

```
const api = introspect.graphql({
    loadSchemaFromString: '',
})
```